# Android: Change height of EditText boxes in TableRow to match eachother after typing?

Tags: android, android-edittext, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm creating a spreadsheet style app in android using a TableLayout and dynamically adding TableRow's containing EditText boxes. My problem is that when one EditText box is edited and the height changes, the height of the other EditText boxes in the same row do not change.

Is there a way to track the height of the editext box being currently edited? I have seen you can add a TextWatcher to an EditText but that only tracks the text being changed and not the EditText box itself

EDIT: Just to clarify, at the moment whe a user enters text into an EditText box in a TableRow the EditText box stretches to fit the content, but the other EditText boxes in the row stay the same. I want a way to track the size changes of the EditText box so that i can make all the heights  of the EditText boxes in a particlar TableRow match the LARGEST one

Comment: try using singleline=true and maxWidth=150dp as your needs.

Comment: I don't want the EditText boxes to be single line though, I want to be able to change the other EditText boxes in the row to match the height of the one being edited (or the biggest one in the row)

Comment: android:maxLines="3" //Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall.